# Options for repeated measures ZINB

Tags: panel-data, zero-inflation

I'm trying to figure out the best way to analyze a dataset on 48 youth who were part of am 8-week summer program. These youth were given time-outs and then their behaviors were recorded during time-out as counts. # of time-outs differs across children (some have 1 time-out, others have 25 time-outs). Dataframe is in LONG format (i.e., each time-out has its own line). I'm interested in examining if affect predicts behavioral counts during time-out. So:

---

DV = behavioral counts
IV = affect, tx week, meds
Offset = Log of # of time-outs in a day

---

I originally ran this in SAS using PROC GENMOD:

```
PROC GENMOD DATA = DATA;
Class Meds; *yes or no
Model behavior = meds time x1 x2 x3 / link = log dist = zinb offset = log_numTOs
ZEROMODEL = meds time x1 x2 x3;
RUN;
```

I ran this and got results that made sense but then realized that REPEATED statements don't work with zero-inflated models, nor are RANDOM statements recognized in this model. I'm not inherently interested in within-person effects, just interested in whether affect predicts behavioral counts. I assume it's important to have the REPEATED effect to note that observations are correlated within child. So, I think I've analyzed this incorrectly.

This brings me to my questions:

1. Am I correct that this has been analyzed incorrectly?
2. I'm seeing that NLMIXED is another way to go, but what do others recommend? I'm not familiar with NLMIXED or R all that much but open to any ideas.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say whether this was a randomized (cross-over?) experiment. If so, the model you describe makes sense.

In that case, an obvious implementation option (as long as you don't mind Bayes) is the `brms` R package, that lets you pretty flexibly combine things like random effects and [zero-inflated models](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_families.html#zero-inflated-and-hurdle-models). Something like a [model specification](http://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/reference/brmsformula.html) like:

```
library(brms)

brm(data=mydata,
    formula = bf( behavior | ~ 1 + (1|p|subject) + meds + time + x1 + x2 + x3 + offset(log_numTOs),
                  zi ~ 1 + (1|p|subject) + meds + time + x1 + x2 + x3,
                  family = zero_inflated_poisson(link = "log", link_zi = "logit")),
   prior = prior(class=b, normal(0,1)) +
           prior(class=Intercept, dpar=zi, normal(0, 3.14)) +
           prior(class=b, normal(0,1), dpar=zi))
```

with suitable priors might be an option. What I wrote as priors are somewhat vague, but you'd also want to do something for the intercept for the main model, but there it really depends on the scale you are working on what makes sense.

If this is not a randomized experiment, you'd need to also model/account for the process of being assigned to interventions (see the [causal inference literature](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/)).

Comment: Thanks for the info. This was not randomized - all youth received the same treatment. Predictors were measured at baseline prior to the program starting, and then time-outs occurred throughout the 8-week program. I've never used brms (or R all that much). I imagine I can google this package to learn more about it (e.g., what priors are, adding in offsets, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

`brms` is a fine solution. If you want to do something more NLMIXED-like, you can use `glmmTMB`. *Advantages*: don't have to mess around with priors, MCMC diagnostics, etc. *Disadvantages*: if your model is too complex for the data to handle, you have fewer options for using priors to regularize the solution (i.e.,  you'll probably have to simplify the model by throwing things away rather than using a continuous prior to downweight unlikely parameter combinations).

```r
glmmTMB(data=mydata,
    formula = behavior ~ 1 + meds + time + x1 + x2 + x3 + offset(log_numTOs)
                         + (1 + meds + time|subject),
    ziformula ~ 1 + meds + time + x1 + x2 + x3,
    family = nbinom2)
```

The `(1|p|subject)` terms in the `brms` formula are doing something that `glmmTMB` can't (currently) do, i.e. modeling correlations between the random intercept in the conditional (count) model and the random intercept in the zero-inflation model (e.g., do children who have higher behavioral counts than the population average also have higher (or lower) zero-inflation probabilities than average?

I've made a few other modeling choices here:

- assuming that `meds` can vary within children (i.e., individual children go on and off meds over the course of the observation period), I've allowed for a *random-slope model* where in addition to allowing each child to vary in their baseline expected count, the model also allows for different time trends (the `time` in `(1 + meds + time | subject)` and different responses to medication for each child
- I did *not* add a subject-level random effect to the zero-inflation component of the model

In general, it is a good idea to identify the *maximal model*, i.e. the model that allows all possibly observable effects (i.e., all effects that varied within children over the observation period) to vary among children, and for all of those random effects to be correlated with each other. If we assume temporarily that `x1`, `x2`, `x3` vary only across subjects (i.e. they're constant for each child over the observation period), then the maximal model is that the intercept (`1`), effect of medication (`med`), and effect of time (`time`) of both the count model and the zero-inflation model all vary across children. This would mean each child had a vector of 6 latent variables, all potentially correlated with each other, so estimating a 6x6 covariance matrix. (In `glmmTMB` you have to model this as two separate 3x3 covariance matrices, with the count effects independent of the z-i effects; in `brms` I think you would write this as `(1+med+time|p|subject)` in both formulas.)

Unless you have a very large data set, this complex a model isn't likely to work out of the box. If you're using `brms` you can choose between simplifying the model (leaving out some random effects terms, using `||` instead of `|` to specify uncorrelated random effects, etc.) *or* using narrow/more informative priors to keep the model out of trouble; if using `glmmTMB` simplification is your only option.

I second Björn's caution about causal effects if (for example) meds are given non-randomly, to children who show more severe behavioural problems ...